# Why must facts be grouped together in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

Say I am listing facts:

```
letter(a).
letter(b).
letter(c).
...
letter(z).
vowel(a).
consonant(b).
consonant(c).
consonant(d).
vowel(e).
consonant(f).
...
consonant(z).
```

If I declare the rules in 'alphabetical' order, I get the following warnings in the console:

```
Warning: /Users/…/prolog-example.pl:31:
  Clauses of vowel/1 are not together in the source-file
Warning: /Users/…/prolog-example.pl:32:
  Clauses of consonant/1 are not together in the source-file
Warning: /Users/…/prolog-example.pl:35:
  Clauses of vowel/1 are not together in the source-file
Warning: /Users/…/prolog-example.pl:36:
  Clauses of consonant/1 are not together in the source-file
Warning: /Users/…/prolog-example.pl:51:
  Clauses of vowel/1 are not together in the source-file
```

But if I do the following:

```
letter(a).
letter(b).
letter(c).
...
letter(z).
consonant(b).
consonant(c).
consonant(d).
...
consonant(z).
vowel(a).
vowel(e).
vowel(i).
vowel(o).
vowel(u).
vowel(y).
```

I dont get the warnings.  Are the warnings just `warnings` or are they actual errors?

Comment: You have two vowel(a). facts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a predicate definition is discontiguous, the predicate should be declared as such using the standard `discontiguous/1` directive before its clauses. In your case:

```
:- discontiguous([
    letter/1,
    vowel/,
    consonant/1
]).
```

If you have discontiguous predicates without corresponding `discontiguous/1` directives, the consequences depend on the used Prolog system. For example, SWI-Prolog and YAP will print warnings but accept all clauses. GNU Prolog will ignore clauses. ECLiPSe will report a compilation error. In the case the Prolog system doesn't throw an error, a warning is usually still printed as a predicate may be detected as discontiguous due to e.g. a simple typo in a clause head.

Answer (score 2):

They are just warnings on some systems. This is to prevent you from accidentally adding clauses to a predicate when you wanted to write a new one. You can get rid of those in SWI (the messages look like the ones you get from SWI, and I haven't used other dialects too much).

You can either use `style_check/1`, or the `discontiugous` directive.

```
:- discontiguous vowel/1,consonant/1,letter/1.
% alternative:
:- style_check(-discontiguous).
```

Comment: They are "just warnings" in **some** Prolog systems.

Comment: @PauloMoura: thanks, i only have SWI now, and it's a long time since i used anything else, edited it in.

Answer (score 2):

The standard ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995 reads on this:

> #### 7.4.3 Clauses
>
> ...
>
> All the clauses for a user-defined procedure `P` shall be
>   consecutive read-terms of a single Prolog text unless there
>  is a
>   directive `discontiguous(UP)` <s>directive</s> indicating `P` in
>   that Prolog text.

So the standards demands (»shall«) that all clauses are consecutive by default. A programmer or program that now relies on the clauses being added nevertheless does not rely on standard behavior.